# what does this sed commands does? please explain its bits and pieces

Tags: regex, sed

Please explain this sed command?

> sed -n "s/[^>]*>/ /gp"

What is gp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks for non-greater-than characters preceding a greater-than symbol, and changes all of them to a single space. Thus, it will convert this input (where I've used _ to indicate a space):

```
foo>_bar> b
x>>_a
```

to

```
___b
___a
```

As Mark notes, "g" means global, and "p" means "print the line".

Answer (score 3):

- `g` means [global](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6): i.e. replace all occurences, not just the first.
- `p` means to [print](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-9) the modified line. Otherwise due to the `-n` switch it would not be printed.

The command finds all lines containing at least one `>` and prints some spaces followed by the text after the final `>`. The number of spaces printed is the number of `>` in the line.

For example if this line is in the input file:

```
123>456>789
```

Then this is printed:

```
  789
```

Answer (score 1):

I was typing up a long explanation, but Brian beat me to it.  To clarify a tiny bit, the "p" prints the modified / matching line.  The "-n" in your command line tells sed to "not print the file".  Combined with the "p", it works kinda like grep, but within the scope of the script (ie, anything it changes/matches).